# How to compute an angle in specific counter-clockwise direction between vectors

Tags: euclidean-geometry

I have one *incoming* vector and multiple *outgoing* vectors in 2D.

I need compute an angle in this way: Imagine an *incoming* vector **parallel** to the **x-axis**. Then the *angle-value* "starts" below the *incoming* vector and increases counter-clockwise.

Please see the example image:
[image: Angles between vectors.]

1. The *incoming* vector is $\overrightarrow{AB}$. *Outgoing* vectors are $\overrightarrow{BC}$, $\overrightarrow{BD}$ and $\overrightarrow{BE}$. By the definition above: $\alpha$ is the smallest angle and $\gamma$ is the biggest angle in this situation.
2. The *incoming* vector is $\overrightarrow{FG}$. *Outgoing* vectors are $\overrightarrow{GH}$ and $\overrightarrow{GJ}$. $\delta <\epsilon$.

I need algorithmicaly select the *outgoing* vector with the smallest angle (defined above).

How can I compute this specific angle?

Comment: What's "Outcoming"? Shouldn't it be "Outgoing"?

Comment: @SanathDevalapurkar Yes, you are right. I corrected it.

Answer (score 0):

1. Translate the picture so the incoming vector ends at the origin. (Subtract the coordinates of its “tip” from every tip and tail.)
2. Reverse the tip and tail of the incoming vector so it has its tail at the origin.
3. Scale each vector by its length, so each has length 1. (Divide each point’s coordinates by the length of the vector it’s an endpoint of.)
4. Find the angle to the translated and scaled incoming vector measured counter-clockwise from the origin. Because it's now a unit vector with tail at the origin, its tip is at $(\cos\theta,\sin\theta)$ for a unique angle $0\le\theta<2\pi$.
5. Rotate everything clockwise around the origin by this angle $\theta$, using the standard rotation transformation taking $(x,y)$ to $(x\cos\theta+y\sin\theta,-x\sin\theta+y\cos\theta)$.
6. Now the tip of each vector is $(\cos\theta,\sin\theta)$ for a different unique angle $0\le\theta<2\pi$. These are the angles you want.